# How to generate AWGN with given power spectral density

Tags: power-spectral-density, gaussian

I am a little unsure about the generation of a additive white Gaussian noise, so I would appreciate to hear from you if I`m doing it correctly.

My goal is to generate the time-domain noise correspondent to a noise floor of -135 dbm/Hz

The procedure I`m adopting is the following:

1 - Convert the noise floor in dbm/Hz to Watts/Hz
2 - Get the average total power from the PSD.
3 - Generate the Gaussian noise with this average total power
4 - Take the FFT of the Gaussian noise and estimate the periodogram to verify whether it is indeed generating the noise with the correct PSD

Here is how I do the 4 steps above:

1 - 
\begin{align} S_\text{watts} = \left(10^{\frac{S_\text{dBm}}{10}}\right)10^{-3} \end{align}
where $S_\text{watts}$ is the PSD in Watts/Hz and $S_\text{dBm}$ is the PSD in dBm/Hz.

2 - Average total power is given by $$ P_n = S_\text{watts} B ,$$ where $B$ is the Bandwidth

3 - Generate the *randn* MATLAB function multiplied by $\sqrt{P_n}$.

4 -
4.1 Take the FFT of the signal, let`s say, $X(k)$.
4.2 Get the Energy Spectral Density (ESD) as $\frac{\left| X(k) \right|^2}{N}$
4.3 Get the PSD by simply dividing the ESD by $N$ (the FFT length)
4.4 I do not simply plot the $10 \log_{10}\left(\text{PSD} 10^3\right)$, since I believe this would plot the PSD in dBm/subcarrier. Instead of this, I plot $10 \log_{10}\left(\frac{\text{PSD}}{\text{tone spacing}} 10^3\right)$, in attempt to get the plot as dBm/Hz.

The code below is what I am using. Please, indicate if I`m doing any mistake.

```
clear all
clc

bandwidth = 106e6;                          % in Hz
sampleFrequency = 2*bandwidth;              % in Hz
noiseFloor = -135;                          % in dBm/Hz
awgnPsd = (10.^(noiseFloor/10))*1e-3;       % in Watts/Hz
noisePower = awgnPsd*2*bandwidth;           % in Watts

% Generate noise signal:
N = 4096;           % signal length
nSymbols = 1000;     % number of symbols with length N to be generated
noise = randn(N,nSymbols)*sqrt(noisePower);

% Verify PSD
toneSpacing = sampleFrequency/N;        % DFT tone spacing           
ESD = mean(abs(fft(noise,N)).^2)/N;     % Energy spectral density
PSD = ESD/N; 


% plot PSD
figure
plot(10*log10((PSD/toneSpacing)*1e3))
```

Comment: An aside: if you want to create a discrete-time simulation of a voltage waveform that represents some power level, you need to take the impedance that the voltage is measured across into account. For RF communication applications, this is often 50 ohms.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Matlab snippet that might help. You should be able to apply the result to your favorite PSD routine to see the dbm/Hz in the frequency domain.

```
% create complex noise with a desired dBm/Hz
fs=1e6;             % whatever you want
N=1e5;              % # samples of noise
R=50;               % ohms
dbm_hz = -135;      % goal
bw = fs;            % complex noise with BW = sample rate
dbm = dbm_hz + 10*log10(bw);
dbw = dbm - 30;
watts = 10^(dbw/10);
vrms = sqrt(watts * R);
n = randn(N,1) + j*randn(N,1);
n = vrms * n / std(n);
meas_dbm_hz = 10*log10(sqrt(mean(n.*conj(n)))^2 / R) - 10*log10(bw) + 30
```